# How to use Index, Match and Product functions in excel for this questions?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, matching

Week #    1    2   3   4   5

Ratio    0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.6

Select week from Drop Down List  ____ (we have 1,2,3,4,5 inside)

So how can we use index,match,product or other excel formulas for performing the following task:

If 3 is selected from the dropdown list, then we multiply 0.9*0.9*0.8

If 2 is selected from dropdown list, then we multiply 0.9*0.9

Can you please help?

I could not find how to use index match or this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PRODUCT` and `INDEX` to achieve this. No need for `MATCH` here. Take a look at this example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G (your dropdown) | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | =PRODUCT(B2:INDEX(B1:F2,2,H1)) |
| 2 | ratio | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 | 0.6 |  |  |

In case your weeks do not start at one, you do have to use `MATCH`:
`=PRODUCT(B2:INDEX(B2:F2,1,MATCH(H1,B1:F1)))`

Answer (score 0):

with  Office 365 you could also do this using `TAKE`:

`=PRODUCT(TAKE(B2:F2,,H1))`

Where `H1` is the dropdown selection:
[image]

Else use `=PRODUCT(B2:INDEX(B2:F2,,H1))`